# What different between Thread in console application with Thread in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, console

i 'm writing a programming in c# with both console application and wpf application with a same code, but have different result.

Here is code in Console application.

```cs
javaAccessBridge = Jab.Instance;
javaAccessBridge.Init();
using (JavaApplication app = new JavaApplication())
{
    JavaApplicationContext context = new JavaApplicationContext()
    {
         ExecutableFile = @"c:\Dev\sq.jar"
     };
    app.Launch(context);
}
Thread.Sleep(5000);
// return 0, not found any jvm instance.
javaAccessBridge.EnumJvms().Count;
```

Here is code in WPF

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    javaAccessBridge = Jab.Instance;
    javaAccessBridge.Init();
}
private void Find_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (JavaApplication app = new JavaApplication())
    {
         JavaApplicationContext context = new JavaApplicationContext()
        {
             ExecutableFile = @"c:\Dev\sq.jar"
        };
        app.Launch(context);
     }
     // count 1 jvm instance.
   List<AccessibleJvm> jvms = javaAccessBridge.EnumJvms();
}
```

i run application then click a button trigger the Find_Click, and jvms.Count =1.
I think the reason is WPF have too thread, one for MainWindow() and second for Find_Click. but seem that is not right.
because i wrote the console application in 2 thread, but the result is not change.

```cs
javaAccessBridge = Jab.Instance;
public void InitLib()
{    
    javaAccessBridge.Init();
}
public void LaunchApp()
{
using (JavaApplication app = new JavaApplication())
{
    JavaApplicationContext context = new JavaApplicationContext()
    {
         ExecutableFile = @"c:\Dev\sq.jar"
     };
    app.Launch(context);
}

Thread init = new Thread(InitLib);
Thread app = new Thread(LaunchApp);
init.Start();
app.Start();
Thread.Sleep(5000);
// still return 0
javaAccessBridge.EnumJvms().Count;
```

Comment: i 'm sorry, but i must comment again for put it to top.